# Rails: querying against compound fields with array of paired values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm in Rails 4.2 (but happy to learn if Rails 5 does something that 4 doesn't), and trying to produce an SQL query (works in Postgres at least) like below:

```
SELECT "mytable".* FROM "mytable" WHERE ((field1, field2) IN ((113, 2), (159, 1), (111, 3))
```

I know that if this was a simple array query like this:

```
SELECT "mytable".* FROM "mytable" WHERE field1 IN (113, 159, 111)
```

I would write this in Rails:

```
where(field1: [113, 159, 111])
```

and Rails/AREL would produce the `WHERE...IN` query for me (and so handle database-engine differences).

I could of course do this to get the effect I want:

```
where("(field1, field2) IN ((113, 2), (159, 1), (111, 3))")
```

but that's not really taking advantage of Rails techniques.

I'm open to structuring my target values into a Hash or Array-of-Arrays (or whatever) if appropriate, but is there a Rails way to do this compound field query **without** resorting to a hardcoded SQL string clause to the `where` method?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you should be able to do:

```
Model.where(field1: [113, 159, 111], field2: [2])
```

Or if you have a hash, then:

```
Model.where(field1: hash.keys, field2: hash.values)
```

Note that this will return all records where field1 is equal to any of the hash keys, and field2 is equal to any of the hash values. If you need to find only fields that match specific pairs, this will not work.

Comment: I clarified the example in my OP since it wasn't clear as I intended.  The query you suggest would give me a basic AND relationship between `field1` and `field2`.   I'm looking for a compound IN one.  In my updated example, I only want 113 if it's paired with a 2 in a given record and only want 159 if it's paired with a 1 in its given record.   An AND would not keep that distinction.  Thx though!

Comment: I think you may be stuck with raw SQL. Not aware of any ActiveRecord equivalent for that. Good luck!

Comment: Thx.  I wonder if its possible with Arel, but haven't had a chance to play with that yet.